# Percona replication not sync

Tags: php, mysql, replication, percona, galera

we use percona cluster 5.7.20 
my wsrep configuration.

```
max_connections = 10000
open_files_limit = 32768
wsrep_sync_wait=1
wsrep_causal_reads=ON
sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
wsrep_provider_options="pc.ignore_quorum=true;pc.ignore_sb=true;gcache.size=2G; gcache.page_size=1G;gcs.fc_limit = 256; gcs.fc_factor = 0.99;"
wsrep_slave_threads=32
[sst]
inno-apply-opts="--use-memory=8G"
compressor="pigz"
decompressor="pigz -d"
```

i did a test for sync replication via php 7 test code.
https://github.com/ureyni/percona_replicationtest

insert value to node1 with a transaction.
after execute commit, do a select query with some value on node2 if data not found, query exec on node3.

the test was not successful.

why? I don't understand because 
all documents on the internet say it's synchronous.

please help.

Answer (score 2):

I would first check that the nodes have actually formed a cluster.

Connect to any of the nodes and run the following query

```
show status like 'wsrep_%';
```

If all 3 nodes are connected, you should see something like the following

```
mysql> show status like 'wsrep%';
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Variable_name              | Value                                |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid     | b598af3e-ace3-11e2-0800-3e90eb9cd5d3 |
...
| wsrep_local_state          | 4                                    |
| wsrep_local_state_comment  | Synced                               |
...
| wsrep_cluster_size         | 3                                    |
| wsrep_cluster_status       | Primary                              |
| wsrep_connected            | ON                                   |
...
| wsrep_ready                | ON                                   |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

If `wsrep_ready` is OFF, then the node has not initialized correctly. You can check the logs to see if an error has occurred.

If `wsrep_cluster_size` is 1, then a cluster has not been formed. The node is acting standalone. The first thing to check would be to see if the `wsrep_cluster_address` variable has been set correctly. This is from the docs

> **wsrep_cluster_address**
>
> Specify the IP addresses of nodes in your cluster. At least one is
>   required for a node to join the cluster, but it is recommended to
>   list addresses of all nodes. This way if the first node in the list
>   is not available, the joining node can use other addresses.

For more information, it's best to look at

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.7/configure.html

Comment: Thanks for help, Cluster is working seem correctly , my problem is after commit on node1 , i did'nt take data from node2 or node3, if i do select stmt 5000 milisecond after insert stmt , i can take data from other nodes. but we use queue for our services , switching between services is very fast, sometimes one service insert data , second service on other server  cant  take data.

Comment: I've used your code as a repro case, Thanks, it was a big help! This is a bug in 5.7.20 and a bug has been created to track the issue

[link to the bug](https://jira.percona.com/browse/PXC-2061)

Comment: @KennTakara Thank you. I seem to have run into this bug as well, and if not for your report of it, I probably never would have found the cause.